# Compilation of IBM's kicked-Ising experiment in terms of Pauli rotations

Tags: compiling, ising-model

I'm following [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.16372.pdf) which classically simulates a kicked-Ising experiment, in response to IBM's recent Nature paper. The quantum circuit in question consists of alternating layers of $R_{ZZ}\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \prod_{\langle i,j \rangle} \text{exp}\left( i \frac{\pi}{2} Z_i Z_j \right) $ and $R_X(\theta_h) = \prod_i \text{exp}\left( - i \frac{\theta_h}{2} X_i \right)$, i.e.
$$U = [R_{ZZ}R_X(\theta_h)]^t$$
for $t$ layers.

The paper then says the following: "Since the entangling gates in $R_{ZZ}$ are Clifford, we first transform the circuit to consist only of non-Clifford Pauli rotation gates $R_{\tilde{X}^{(m)}}$ where $\tilde{X}_i^{(m)} = (R_{ZZ}^\dagger)^m X_i R_{ZZ}^m$." (Presumably $m \in \{0,1\}$.)

I assume the point here is that they want to absorb the Clifford $R_{ZZ}$ gates into the non-Clifford $R_X(\theta_h)$ gates so that the whole circuit consists only of non-Clifford Pauli rotations. However, I don't understand how they're doing this using the transformation above. Could someone perhaps give a decomposition of a single circuit layer in terms of these $R_{\tilde{X}^{(m)}}$ gates?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I belive in the IBM experiment the only non-Clifford gates in the circuit are a layer of $R_X$ gates at the beginning. The $R_{ZZ}$ gates are set to a Clifford angle of $R_{ZZ}(-\pi/2)$. This allows them to decompose each $R_{ZZ}$ gate using only a single CNOT.

Comment: @Callum Yes, that's right. The paper I've linked to is one of the 'response papers' which classically simulates the whole thing. The authors transform the whole circuit into only non-Clifford rotation gates using the transformation above, which is what I can't get my head around.

Comment: Hmm yeah I've seen the response paper as well. I'm not totally clear on the details yet. I'll see if I can figure it out.